# Retrieve Header row for DataGridView control

Tags: c#, datagridview, header

I am writing a class to print the contents of a DataGridView, however I'm having trouble extracting the names of the header row. I'm using .NET 3.0.

Is there an easy way of doing this?
I have seen some methods whereby the controls collections are used, E.g.

```
columnTitle = myDataGrid.Controls[0].Controls[0].Text;
```

however I've yet to get this to work either.

To extract the table contents I use:

```
cellText = m_dataGrid[row.Index, col.Index].Value.ToString();
```

Is there not a similar way of accessing the column names...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dataGridView.Columns[0].Name  should give you the column name for column 0.

```
foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView.Columns)
 Console.Out.WriteLine(col.Name);
```

Comment: Nice one. I knew it would be something silly and obvious! Thanks for the quick response.